# How do you pass an arbitrary bit of data to a user control in ASP.NET MVC using Html.RenderPartial()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a strongly typed user control ("partial") and I'd like to be able to pass it some additional information from its containing view.  For example, I have view that's bound to a product class and i have a partial that also is strongly typed to that same model, but I also need to pass an additional parameter for imageSize to my partial.  I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("_ProductImage", ViewData.Model, new { imageSize = 100 }); %>
```

As far as I know there is no way to do this, but I'm hoping that someone smarter than me may have a solution ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the type of the partial model:

```
class PartialModel 
{
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }
    public ParentModelType ParentModel { get; set; }
}
```

Now pass it:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("_ProductImage", 
    new PartialModel() { ImageSize = 100, ParentModel = ViewData.Model }); %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the most beautiful solution

```
<% ViewData["imageSize"] = 100; %>

<% Html.RenderPartial("_ProductImage"); %>
```

the ViewData is passed by default

Answer (score 1):

I use a generic class model - which is similar in concept to the approach suggested by Craig.

I kind of wish MS would create an overload to `RenderPartial` to give us the same functionality. Just an additional `object data` parameter would be fine.

Anyway, my approach is to create a PartialModel which uses generics so it can be used for all .ascx controls.

```
 public class PartialControlModel<T> : ModelBase 
    {
        public T ParentModel { get; set; }
        public object Data { get; set; }

        public PartialControlModel(T parentModel, object data) : base()
        {
            ParentModel = parentModel;
            Data = data;
        }
    }
```

The .ascx control should inherit from the correct `PartialControlModel` if you want the view to be strongly typed, which most likely you do if you've got this far.

```
public partial class ThumbnailPanel : 
                     ViewUserControl<PartialControlModel<GalleryModel>>
```

Then you render it like this :

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ThumbnailPanel", 
new PartialControlModel<GalleryModel>(ViewData.Model, tag)); %>
```

Of course when you refer to any parent model items you must use this syntax :

```
ViewData.Model.ParentModel.Images
```

You can get the data and cast it to the correct type with :

```
ViewData.Model.Data
```

If anyone has a suggestion on how to improve the generics I'm using please let me know.